# Attribute field collection or grid

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I would like to add a collection type attribute.
A field with several informations.

It's like field_collection of drupal8.

I was thinking about a grid, but is it possible to add a grid attribute?

In my product I want to add a field (duplicable) that contains: a title, a text and an image.

Which procedure do you recommend?

Comment: You want to add new product attributes and need to show that attribute to product grid ?

Comment: I want to add new attribut, but attribut is collection or grid.